How to retrieve che correct date column from custom action in Grid4PHP?
I'm using Grid4PHP in my project and I have an issue retrieving a data value.
In my table I have a data column:
data    date
id      int(11)
...other fields

Here my relevant code:
$db_conf = array(
    "type"      => PHPGRID_DBTYPE,
    "server"    => PHPGRID_DBHOST,
    "user"      => PHPGRID_DBUSER,
    "password"  => PHPGRID_DBPASS,
    "database"  => PHPGRID_DBNAME
);

$g = new jqgrid($db_conf);

function setup_options($g, $table, $title=null) :void {
    $caption = $title;
    if ($caption == null) $caption = str_replace("_", " ", $table);
    $opt["caption"] = ucwords($caption);
    $opt["forceFit"] = true;
    $opt["rownumbers"] = true;
    $opt["rownumWidth"] = 50;
    $opt["autoresize"] = true;
    $opt["autowidth"] = true;
    $opt["resizable"] = false;
    $opt["height"] = "100%";
    $opt["globalsearch"] = true;
    $opt["toolbar"] = "bottom";
    $opt["toppager"] = false;
    $opt["pgbuttons"] = true;
    $opt["cellEdit"] = true;
    $opt["reloadedit"] = true;

    $g->table = $table;
    $g->set_options($opt);
    $g->set_actions(array(
        "add" => true,
        "delete" => true,
        "edit" => true,
        "autofilter" => true,
        "search" => "simple",
        "export_excel" => true,
        "export_pdf" => true,
        "export_csv" => true,
        "export_html" => true,
    ));
}

function setup_table($g): void {   
    $col = array();
    $col["name"] = "data";
    $col["formatter"] = "date";
    $col["formatoptions"] = array("srcformat"=>'Y-m-d',"newformat"=>'d/m/Y');
    $cols[] = $col;

    $col = array();
    $col["title"] = " ";
    $col["name"] = "more_actions";
    $col["fixed"] = true;
    $col["width"] = "40";
    $col["align"] = "center";
    $col["search"] = false;
    $col["sortable"] = false;
    $buttons_html = '<a class="ui-custom-icon ui-icon ui-icon-locked" title="copy" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="copy_to_fixed({data})"></a>';
    $col["default"] = $buttons_html;
    $cols[] = $col;

    $g->set_columns($cols, true);
}

$g->select_command = "custom query";

setup_options($g, "mytable");
setup_table($g);
$table = $g->render("mytable");

?>

<?php include ('header.php'); ?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <?php include('navigation.php'); ?>
        <div class="col py-3">
            <?php echo $table ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function copy_to_fixed(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
</script>

For example 2024-09-11 (as in the db) is shown as 11/09/2024 but the printed value is 2004. Should I use any conversion function to retrieve the actual value?
I'm afraid it makes the math even without eval: 2024 - 9 - 11 = 2004!
I tried with:

console.log(String(data))
console.log("'" + data + "'"))

